# Copying columns to a new list

Tags: 2013, site-column

I currently have a list that is reaching 40k threshold, so i want to create a new list so it can break it up by area (Central, Midstate, Western). I am going to create few more lists and move the data over. Is there a way to copy over my columns into my new lists? This is all in one same sharepoint site.
The reason i ask this is because alot of my columns are lookups or numeric fields..

Answer (score 3):

[image]Make the list a template and don't include the data.  You can make new lists from this template and even add additional columns to the new lists without affecting the original.

Comment: how do i include specfic data?

Comment: It is a check box on the template creation page.  It is a yes or no/ all or none.  You can always delete data after it is created.  I never have, but theoretically, you could make a temporary template to preserve you original then remove what you don't want and make a 2nd final template.  Please mark as answer if this helps.

Comment: i dont see the check box to yes or no... can you screenshot

Comment: Included pic of choice to include content in answer